# How to force Content-type html?

Tags: html, .htaccess, content-type

I have a bunch of html files in my web-page that do not end with .html. This never gave me any trouble, all browsers always treated the files correctly.

Now that I've migrated to SSL (https instead of http), those files are not recognized as html anymore by browsers, instead as app/octet-stream, and ask me what I want to do with them when I try to open.

How can I fix this on the server side? I tried fiddling with the .htaccess file, writing

```
RedirectMatch permanent /photo/birdindexframes/([^\.]*)$ /photo/birdindexframes/$1.html
```

and moving each  to <file.html>, but this is not working.

Also not working:

```
<FilesMatch "^[^.]+$">
ForceType text/html
</FilesMatch>


<Files "^[^.]+$">
ForceType text/html
</Files>
```

If necessary, I have access to the system administrator.

Comment: Try adding `Header set Content-Type "text/html"` as well in `FilesMatch` block. Are you sure this .htaccess is being used for your `https` site?

Comment: You nailed it: my .htaccess is not working. Is there something I can do?

Comment: You will have to check `VirtualHost` config to enable it

Comment: I don't have root access to the server.

Comment: The admin migrated to *nginx*, which does not use anything similar to .htaccess. :(